# Smooth Urysohn function having $0$ as regular value

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a manifold and $C_0,C_1$ be two disjoint closed subsets of $M$ , then smooth Urysohn Lemma says that there exists a smooth function $f:M\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(C_0)=\{0\},f(C_1)=\{1\}$.

Is it always possible to choose such a smooth Urysohn function such that $0$ is a regular value of $f$ i.e. at each point of $x\in f^{-1}(0)$ the derivative map $df_x:T_x(M)\rightarrow T_0([0,1])=\Bbb R$ is a surjective.

Comment: What happens when $C_0$ is a closed interval?

Comment: I think I have done . If I choose $M=\Bbb R$ and $C_0=[1,2]$ then $f|_{C_0}$ will be a submersion but $dim([1,2])=1$ hence $f|_{C_0}$ will be an immersion also hence derivative will be isomorphism and now inverse function theorem will gives the contradiction. Am I right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's never possible (except in the trivial case when $C_0=\emptyset$). If $x$ is any point of $C_0$, the fact that $df_x$ is surjective implies that $x$ has a neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ on which $f\colon M\to\mathbb R$ is a submersion. Since every submersion is an open map, the image of $f$ would have to contain a neighborhood of $0$, which is impossible since $f$ takes its values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Actually I was doing the problem : If $M$ is a manifold with boundary then there exists a smooth non-negative function $f$ on $M$ such that $\partial M=f^{-1}(0)$ and $0$ is a regular value of $f$. That's why this question arises in mind. Can give me some hints for this problem.

Comment: @UserD: Ah, if $M$ is a manifold with boundary, it's a whole different story. Can you see how to do it locally in a coordinate neighborhood?